# SQL Try-Catch and transactions issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions

I have a transaction like this and I have a few questions about it.

If I were to run this against 'Master' where it should error because the table 'Year' does not exist I do not see the transaction rollback. SQL simply throws errors that the table/columns do not exists.

If I run it against a database where the table exists and make it error because of a foreign key constraint then I do see the transaction rollback.

Why do I not get the same results.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO Year (YearId, FiscalYear) 
    VALUES (NewId(), 2014)

    COMMIT

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
     ROLLBACK
        PRINT 'ERROR'

  DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000)
        , @ErrSeverity int
  SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
         @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

  RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
END CATCH

GO
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess that when the table does not exist, the error occurs when the code is parsed/compiled and never executed, so there is no transaction to rollback.

While when the table exists, the code must be executed and the transaction is started. The error then causes the rollback.

Comment: Your guess is correct :) - catch is for runtime errors, not compile time errors.